# Getting generated HTML via AJAX is a bad practice?

Tags: ajax

I can receive JSON.

Is this a bad practice? And if so, who said that? W3C?

No personal opinion, please

Referencies links will be good.

Comment: Surely all best/bad practices come down to opinion in the end (possibly deferring to the opinion of another entity, but still...)?

Comment: Just a little note about error pages: If you use custom error pages, ajax will get it's content. (like time outs and/or 500 errors)

Comment: This question use personal opinion, but if W3C says that is a bad practice, it's based on personal opinion but ins't a opinion, like if php group says 'doing foo with php is a bad practice', this ins't a opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea being that HTML is bigger than json, so where possible, update the existing page using json content.

Comment: But then you have to manually generate the HTML nodes based on that javascript.  Which can be nice, but it means you have to write a lot more javascript.  It's far simpler to say "get html and stuff in here".  I think this topic may be too hard to generalize on since different needs call for different tactics.

Comment: Yes, I agree - depends on the use case I guess. If you were replacing data in a table hundreds of times using AJAX then Json would be quicker for isntance.